# How can I turn off primary checks for database

Tags: mysql, duplicates, primary-key

If someone wants to turn off the foreign key checks the statement 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0' is used. Is there a MySQL statement to turn off all primary key checks.

Comment: I doubt it ([no](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html)). The primary key is kind of important... Why do you think you need this?

Comment: I updated magento, now I want to import the db to my local. but I was unable to do so, because the magento upgrade added some duplicate entries for primary keys or what so over. I have founded some duplicate records but that are not important to me, because they really are duplicate entries of some sales.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable non-unique keys in MyISAM tables by using `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS`, but primary and unique keys can't be switched off unless you remove them from the table.